# Attach an event handler to HTML rendered in an IFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I am working on designing a react application that will be used to view a number of different types  of files, from a known source. The user will search, be presented with a list of results, and then upon clicking one of the results, I will fetch the file, and want to display it on the screen as well. These files are all HTML/XML.

On top of this, I want to attach event handlers to certain tags within the file itself. (ie. attaching an `onClick` listener to all `<p>` tags, for example)

The obvious answer would be to use an iframe, however then the event handlers become a problem. Using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` also works, however if there's a better solution I would love to know about it. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can fire events from an iframe and handle it by its parent by using this code

```
//iframe
function buttonClick() {
  parent.$(parent.document).trigger('eventhandler');
}
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Button</button>

//parent
 $(document).on('eventhandler', function () {
     alert('event fired');
 });
```

Just add the event handler in parent file and add your logic in it and then add event trigger in child iframe file or you can also follow [this link](https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html).